# Open url in mail body

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my iPhone application I have a possibility to send mail. In the body on the mail I have url. code is like bellow.

```
- (IBAction)sendEmailClick:(UIButton *)sender{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        NSString* message = @"Click link below to reach the shared file(s).<br /><br /> http://google.com <br /><br /> Do you want to try our product? Please visit <a href=\"http://www.test.com/\">http://www.test.com/</a>";        

        MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [controller setSubject:@"Shared file from App"];
        [controller setMessageBody:message isHTML:YES];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        controller.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    } else {
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"App", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Your phone is not currently configured to send mail.", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

I have enabled javascript but after I click on url in mail it doesn't open with browser.

Comment: Are you clicking on link after sending it, since your copy works for me

Comment: I click on it in editing mode before send mail

Comment: That might not happen, pls try sending mail and then try opening it

Comment: so it is not possible to open url before sending mail?

Comment: My experience says no